# How can I use a Ruby module in another module?

Tags: ruby

This code doesn't seem to work - it can't figure out some_func was defined. Why not?

```
# in file 1
def ModuleA
  def some_func
    "boo"
  end
end

# in file 2
def ModuleB
  include ModuleA

  MY_CONSTANT = some_func
end
```

Comment: You said "This code doesn't seem to work".  Be specific! For example, "When I attempt to execute this code, I get the following error when the line `MY_CONSTANT = some_func` is parsed:  `SyntaxError: (irb):22: dynamic constant assignment`.  Can someone explain why I am getting this error?"

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring your modules wrong and you need to `extend` not `include`

```
module ModuleA
  def some_func
    "boo"
  end
end

module ModuleB
  extend ModuleA
  MY_CONSTANT = some_func
end
```

Comment: I think you should say only that `extend` should be used if the intent is to use `some_func` as a class method, as we cannot infer that that is what the asker wants to do.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Well, he's calling it like a *class method*, so let's assume that's the intention.

Comment: Yes, this was the best "fix" to his broken code. His original code used it like a class method so that's what I kept.

Answer (score 1):

In your code example, you use the `include` directive.

This means that all the methods defined in `ModuleA` are included into `ModuleB` as **instance methods**.

However, by then invoking `some_func` in the module body of `ModuleB`, you try to invoke it as if it was defined as a **class method** on `ModuleB` (which it is not, since you have used `include` before).

If you actually want to define (and call) it as a class method, then you need to use `extend ModuleA` inside `ModuleB` to add the method definition.